# can i make the iframes inside a section have an inline-block display?

Tags: html, css

i've been trying to design a project i'm currently working on for uni but to no avail .. i want to have the 3 iframes displayed inline-block (such as i1 next to i2 next to i3).i know i've abused the classes but my brain won't take it anymore.. 
here is my html code:

```html
<section class="trailer">
<h2>Media</h2>
    <article>
        <h3>CHILDREN OF NOBODY - OFFICIAL TRAILER</h3>
        <iframe src="videos/teaser.mp4" class="trailer"></iframe>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h3>Official page</h3>
        <iframe src="http://www.imbc.com/broad/tv/drama/childrenofnobody/" class="trailer"></iframe>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h3>Making video</h3>
        <iframe src="videos/makingvideo.mp4" class="trailer"></iframe>
    </article>
</section>
```

and my css:

```css
.trailer>iframe{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    border-top: #c00 10px dotted;
    border-right: #c00 20px dotted;
    border-left: #c00 20px dotted;
    border-bottom: #c00 40px dotted;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your iFrames are inside of an article tag you will need to apply the inline-block style to the article tag and not the iFrame.

```
.trailer article {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked and it actually makes sense lol. thanks again, much appreciated